# Preventing head node from being pushed into linked list

Tags: c++

I am writing some code in which the user can input certain information; and that gets pushed back into a linked list... It is all working aside from the fact that there are an extra set of 0's being added to the end of the list because of these lines here:

How the user inputs the info:

```
int sizeOf = 0, i = 0, itemStock = 0;//, individualItemCost = 0;
string name;
double individualItemCost = 0;
cout << "How many lines would you like to input: " << endl;
cin >> sizeOf;  

//Create a head node(first element)...
Stock* head = buildNode(name, itemStock, individualItemCost);

//Each time, create a new node and push onto the list...
while (i < sizeOf)
{
    /*cout << "Please enter the students name: " << endl;
    cin >> head->itemName;
    cout << "Please enter the item stock: " << endl;
    cin >> head->itemStock; 
    cout << "Please enter the item price: " << endl;
    cin >> head->individualItemCost;    */

    cout << "Please enter the students name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Please enter the item stock: " << endl;
    cin >> itemStock;   
    cout << "Please enter the item price: " << endl;
    cin >> individualItemCost;  

    //push(head,head->itemName, head->itemStock, head->individualItemCost);  //Push back everything in head
    push(head,name, itemStock, individualItemCost);  //Push back everything in head
    i++;

}
```

Buildnode function:

```
    Stock* buildNode(string itemName, int itemStock, double individualItemCost)
{
    Stock* s = new Stock;
    s->itemName = itemName;
    s->itemStock = itemStock;
    s->individualItemCost = individualItemCost;
    s->next = nullptr;
    return s;
}
```

How I push ti onto the list:

```
void push(struct Stock*& list, string itemName, int itemStock, double individualItemCost)
{
    Stock* newnode = new Stock;
    newnode->itemName = itemName;
    newnode->itemStock = itemStock;
    newnode->individualItemCost = individualItemCost;
    newnode->next = list;
    list = newnode;
}
```

I just need some help in only inputting what the user inputs, not the head also.

Comment: why you have commented out code? It doesn't matter but it really does not help in focusing in the problem

Comment: Your `push` function does a `push_front` not a `push_back` contrary as your comment.

Comment: Just initialize `Stock* head` with `nullptr` instead of your extra unwanted node.

Comment: Your push function places new node in front.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are initializing your `head` with a Node having `0` values?

Think like this, when started, `head` is `null`..

As your `push` method adds new node at the front of the list, it will add a new node even there isn't any other node in your list. you just need to change the line

```
Stock* head = buildNode(name, itemStock, individualItemCost);
```

to

```
Stock* head = null;
```

Hope it helped...

Comment: Hmmmm, this has partially worked thanks! But now it is only looping through the first two items in the linked list

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Consider using the container classes, e.g. std::list (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).